# App rejected due to unsafe encryption - with no clues except q0.e0.c

Tags: flutter, android-security

Trying to publish an app and got the following:

Unsafe Encryption

Your app contains unsafe cryptographic encryption patterns. Please see this Google Help Center article for details.

q0.e0.c

Unfortunately got nothing else, no email, no other detail, so just at a total loss as to the code its referring to.
Closest I could find were the ApiKeys used by RevenueCat. As a test I removed these and uploaded a build ... same issue so thats not it.
also tried with obfuscation - no joy.

Can anyone point me in a direction I can even figure out what code its objecting to???

Thanks

for reference here is my dependency list:

```
firebase_core: ^2.6.1
firebase_auth: ^4.2.8
flutter_phoenix: ^1.0.0
nfc_manager: ^3.2.0
flutter_vibrate: ^1.3.0
permission_handler: ^10.0.1
provider: ^6.0.2
package_info_plus: ^3.0.2
geolocator: ^9.0.2
latlong2: ^0.8.1
flutter_map: ^0.14.0  
scrollable_positioned_list: ^0.3.2
flutter_keyboard_visibility: ^5.2.0
numberpicker: ^2.1.1
country_picker: ^2.0.14
o_color_picker: ^1.0.2
flutter_spinbox: ^0.13.0
url_launcher: ^6.1.0
cloud_firestore: ^4.3.1
shared_preferences: ^2.0.13
soundpool: ^2.3.0
excel: ^2.0.4
sn_progress_dialog: ^1.0.6
device_info_plus: ^8.0.0
flutter_contacts: ^1.1.4
what3words: ^3.1.0
connectivity_plus: ^3.0.2
qr_code_scanner: ^1.0.0
purchases_flutter: ^4.10.2
uuid: ^3.0.7
app_links_web: ^1.0.0
connectivity_plus_web: ^1.2.5
device_info_plus_web: ^0.0.1
path_provider: ^2.0.13
file_picker: ^5.2.6
get_file_contents_from: ^0.0.5
intl: ^0.17.0
path: ^1.8.2
positioned_tap_detector_2: ^1.0.4
```

UPDATE!!!! - & FIX (kind of)

Hi All,
First, Thanks to Magnus for the reformat - I am smarter.

Resorted to brute force approach. I carved up my app removing packages and just deleting blocks of code. I then uploaded the packages and left them for google to pre-check (not submitting any for review as none of them worked). Sure enough, I found one that did not trigger the unsafe encryption flag.

Turns out it was nothing to do with firebase/revenueCat or obfuscation. It was a package I had commissioned last year from a freelancer to read ACS NFC card readers. Had published ok previously, just now an issue.

Anyway, I have now published my app (Checkpoint Marshal, a competitor tracking app for charity events), without the offending code in the android version (iOS is just fine.)

Thanks to all who gave me pointers and help.

Comment: Please format the code properly

Comment: update: After latest mods trying to find solution (updated dependencies) the code returned has changed to: o0.e0.c
Very helpful. Thanks Google. starting to get a bit annoyed with the lack of information from Google on this. Wasted 2 days on this and its now taking up a weekend - Fully working app, fine on iOS - Google - the computer says no.

Comment: make sure you had signed your app , if you hadn't search for it . there is official doc from flutter team

Comment: This is because your app obfuscated when uploaded to Google Play, thus the stack trace is like `q0.e0.c`. You could try to deobfuscate , there is an article for deobfuscating stacktraces but there is a chance that deobfuscating just the package you provided will also work https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-deobfuscate-an-android-stacktrace-using-a-mapping-file/